# Unity3D, Why can't I find GameObject from different scene?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I access a GameObject from the active scene this works:

```
GameObject.Find("Something").GetComponent<InputField>().text
```

However from a script that's linked to another scene it doesn't.

I've made sure to add `DontDestroyOnLoad (gameObject)` but still I can't access it, why?

```
private void Start () 
{
    Instance = this;

    //not destroying it when changing scene
    DontDestroyOnLoad (gameObject);
}
```

Comment: can you add the code where you call DontDestroyOnLoad() ?

Comment: Just edited my question with it. Thanks!

Comment: Is this script attached to that GameObject called *"Something"*?

Comment: When you get this problem, have you transitioned from the scene with the object *to* the one without?

Comment: @Programmer yes it is

Comment: @Draco18s yes exactly

Comment: I bet the object is still there, it's just that the canvas that it was attached to is destroyed.

Comment: @Iggy I think the-same thing too. Check if `GameObject.Find("Something")` is null first. If it is not then the InputField is no longer there.

Comment: You guys are right it is null. So how can I not destroy it? I've tried to add 'DontDestroyOnLoad(Something)' but that must not be how it works.

Comment: try to do the same to all of its parents root.

Comment: Thanks @itay421 but I get an error when I do DontDestroyOnLoad to its parent. I'm really stuck with this. On the script I want to access "Something" I put 'GameObject.Find ("Something").GetComponent<InputField> ().text' did I do this wrong?

Comment: "I get an error." Well...what error is it?